# Changing the name of the "users" table to account Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Fairly new to Laravel and would like to follow the table conventions I'm used to.

The default table name for accounts is "**users**" and I'd like to change it to "**account**." If anything, I'd like to change it to "user" and remove the plural.

I've already used migrate to make a cloned table of users called "**account**" and I'm just trying to figure out what all I have to do to existing code to make it work for logging in

It looks like I'll have to somehow update "**app/Http/Auth/AuthController.php**", but I'm not quit sure what it is I'll have to do...

Do I need to:

- Update "use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;"?
- Update in AuthController "**returnUser::create**" to "**returnAccount::create**"? If so do I need to go somewhere else in the code where that class User is being created?

I guess another option is just scrapping their AuthController and establishing my own and just calling a new object of Account... Is this the route I should take?

Comment: It is a widely accepted and used convention to use plural for the name of the tables and singular for the classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply extend the User class and overrule some things if you want to have the Model named Account:

Edit the table property in the Account class, see: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php#L24

```
Account extends User {
    protected $table = 'accounts';
}
```

Once your class Account is created edit the configured authentication class, see:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L31

If you only want to overrule the table used by User, edit the User class:

```
protected $table = 'accounts';
```

---

To be honest, why bother? Taylor provided this skeleton for you to kickstart your application, why not use that especially if you're new to Laravel?

Comment: Extending the User model is not necessary, since OP only mentions using a different table name. Other than that, I agree with your answer.

Comment: I was under that same impression, but I was not sure because OP also mentioned renaming the model name while creating. @hkan

Comment: This is a remodel and the site is not my own but the company's. We have company conventions we have to stick to. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @dom I feared as much ;)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, create account(s) migration - plural is widely acceptable

Migration must contain all important fields

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateAccountsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
       });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('accounts');
    }
}
```

Then create Account model,

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
class Account extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{
     use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

     protected $table = 'accounts';

     protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

     protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

head over to `config\auth.php` and change this line:
 `'model' => App\User::class,`
to
 `'model' => App\Account::class,`